# Water Pressure Boosters Keep Leaking

Tags: plumbing

I've been through 4 different water pressure boosters in the past 2 years with all of them eventually leaking.  I'm beginning to suspect that something in my system setup is the culprit, not just bad luck.  The system is pretty simple:

```
Domestic -> Booster -> Filters -> House
```

Could something like expansion from the hot water heater cause this?  Something else?

Comment: Are talking about a jet pump for a well system?

Comment: Booster to increase poor flow on a city supplied system?

Comment: I would want at least a small tank after the booster the booster should have a check valve built in but if not one should be added and that should increase your pump life.

Comment: I want more information, is it splitting the casing? What material is it made of? Constant leaks at the same connection could indicate a dielectric issue, like a iron - copper junction. Nobility plays a role in corrosion. If it's a pressure related issue a potable cushion tank with a check valve will help. Also cut in and cut out set points could be the culprit. More info is needed.

Comment: The most recent pump is this one: https://us.grundfos.com/products/find-product/SCALA2.html  It started leaking from inside the unit after just a couple months.

Comment: This is directly from the installation manual, but I don't think it will satisfy your problem  "Shaft seal run-in The shaft-seal faces are lubricated by the pumped liquid, meaning that there may be a certain amount of leakage from the shaft seal.When the pump is started up for the first time, or when the shaft seal has been replaced, a certain run-in period is required before the leakage is reduced to an acceptable level. The time required for this depends on the operating conditions, that is, every time the operating conditions change, a new run-in period will be started."